# JQuery Input Auto Suggest code (No plugins)

Tags: jquery

I have an input type text where to user will insert locations, so it can be hardcoded as there are only a few locations.

What I need is if the location starts with N as soon as the user types N or n the input would suggest of auto complete it.

Is there away to do this without using the autosuggest plugin?

Comment: Looks like you've got yourself a project

Comment: So it's not something that is simple to do?

Comment: It's not that hard, but I suppose it depends on *why* you're averse to using a plug-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't need *full* cross-browser implementation, you can always consider using the `datalist`, from HTML 5:

```
<input list="countries" />
<datalist id="countries">
    <option value="Algeria" />
    <option value="Azerbaijan" />
    <option value="United Arab Emirates" />
    <option value="United Kingdom" />
    <option value="United States" />
    <option value="Nicaragua" />
    <option value="Nigeria" />
</datalist>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Lj6qG/1/).

References:

- [`datalist` (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)
- [`datalist` (W3C)](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/datalist).
- [Support for `datalist` (*limited*)](http://caniuse.com/datalist).

Comment: Perfect Solution in my case :)

Comment: In which case I'm glad to have been of help! =)